# Transistor switching problem

Tags: arduino-uno

With my team we constructed a circuit using Arduino. The circuit works on the Proteus simulator. It worked fine with LEDs connected directly to Arduino outputs.

However, when I used Arduino output to trigger a BC 337 transistor to try and actuate a 12 V DC coiled relay, it wouldn't trigger. I measured voltage across transistor collector and emitter, it reads 12 V, just like the source I gave... (The transistor is not switched on I guess).

Supply for the Arduino is a constant 5 V DC.

Where have I gone wrong? Picture as uploaded.

[image: Full circuit]

Furthermore, we are trying to build a controller for an ice making machine. The power circuit (12 V) is to be controlled by Arduino through the transistors.

I am uploading the codes we used and the full circuit diagram.

```
const int start = 13;
const int comp= 2;
const int cond=3;
const int hGas=4;
const int wbut=12;
const int watersol=5;
const int dumper=6;
const int iced=11;

int startButton=0;
int waterButton=0;
int dumperlimswitch=0;

void setup() {

  pinMode(start, INPUT);    
  pinMode(comp, OUTPUT);    
  pinMode(cond, OUTPUT);    
  pinMode(hGas, OUTPUT);    
  pinMode(wbut,INPUT);    
  pinMode(watersol, OUTPUT);    
  pinMode(dumper, OUTPUT);    
  pinMode(iced, INPUT);
}

void loop() {

startButton = digitalRead(start);
waterButton = digitalRead(wbut);

 if (startButton == HIGH) {

    digitalWrite(comp, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(cond, HIGH);

    waterButton = digitalRead(wbut);
    if (waterButton == HIGH){
      digitalWrite(watersol,HIGH);
      }
    else{
      digitalWrite(watersol,LOW);
      }
     delay(800);
    digitalWrite(hGas,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(cond, LOW);

    waterButton = digitalRead(wbut);
    if (waterButton == HIGH){
      digitalWrite(watersol,HIGH);
      }
    else{
      digitalWrite(watersol,LOW);
      }
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(hGas, LOW);
    digitalWrite(dumper, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(cond, HIGH);

    waterButton = digitalRead(wbut);
    if (waterButton == HIGH){
      digitalWrite(watersol,HIGH);
      }
    else{
      digitalWrite(watersol,LOW);
      }
    delay(800);
    digitalWrite(dumper, LOW);
  } 
else {
    digitalWrite(comp, LOW);
    digitalWrite(cond, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: Circuit...? Code...?

Comment: What's an ardinho?

Comment: @gre_gor It's what you get after you use a "Harduino".

Comment: What is pin 13 doing?  Are you putting 12V into p13?  Can you take the Arduino out of the equation, just supply 5V out into the wire that would have been pin 2?  I don't think your problem is an Arduino one, it would have been nice to see the code, but if its working with LEDs then it looks like an electronics issue and would be better on Electronics Exchange.  But if you include Arduino in it they will send it back here :)

Comment: Where is your second image? I can't find the URL of the second image in any of the previous edits. I have reinstated the first image for you already.

Comment: i have now uploaded the correct one. thanks.

Comment: Why are there still two dead links to the second image in the middle of the question? Please tidy up your question, and place the image in a suitable location, rather than right at the top (I would suggest placing it just beneath `Where have I gone wrong? Picture as uploaded.`. Two people have attempted to tidy the question for you. Please take the time to see how they did it, and try to follow their example. A well presented question will get [better quality] answers. Oh, and welcome to SE Arduino, BTW! :-)

Comment: Thanks, your question looks much better now, and is on its way to being reopened :-). BTW, if you are addressing your comment to someone, as you did to me in your last comment, you need to add @<username>, (i.e. @greenonline) in order for that person to receive notification that you have messaged them, otherwise they may never see that comment. I only saw your comment because I was reviewing the question at the time that the comment was posted.

Comment: thanks @Greenonline, i am not so conversant with online protocols. but alas, it seems my question may still not be good enough.

Comment: @Greenonline - I broke the image links not the OP.  Sorry :(

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but that was the first image, that is not the problem, it was the second image that  disappeared. Anyway, not to worry :-)

Comment: @Majenko , now circuit and code posted, does it make sense now?

Comment: Why are there no resistors on your LEDs?

Comment: @majenko , arduino output is capable of upto 50ma current , the LEDs draw so much less, so we supposed, no need of resistors for the current limiting purpose.

Comment: Wrong on both counts. Learn basic electronics and how to count.

Comment: Arduino IO is 40mA *absolute maximum* and 25mA recommended maximum sustained.

Comment: An ideal LED will draw an infinite amount of current.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2017/03/20/what-exactly-is-a-gpio-pin/

Comment: Remove the LEDs or add resistors to them (1k is all you need for indicator LEDs like that) and watch the circuit spring to life.

Answer (score 2):

**TL/DR:** Your LEDs without resistors are diverting all the current away from the transistors so they are unable to switch.

**In detail:**

Let's take a quick look at just one small portion of your circuit in more detail:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZQGhK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have added an extra resistor into the circuit - Rw - which represents the resistance of the wires and pins of the LED, and I have given it a nominal 0.1Ω value.

Now, let's say you set the GPIO HIGH, so it outputs 5V. The LED, D1, is a typical red LED with a forward voltage of, say, 2V.  Let's calculate the current through the LED.

- I = (V<sub>CC</sub> - V<sub>F</sub>)/R = (5 - 2) / 0.1 = 3 / 0.1 = 30A

30A?! But the GPIO can't provide more than 40mA *absolute maximum*. So all that *can* come from the GPIO is being sent straight through the LED leaving nothing (much) for the transistor.

Oh and yes, all that current demand is doing unspeakable damage to the Arduino's GPIO pin.

The transistor's Base-Emitter junction has about a 0.7V drop across it, and, if it weren't for the LED, with the 1kΩ resistor that gives (5-0.7)/1000 = 4.3mA. Which with a h<sub>FE</sub> of around 100, would give a collector current of around 430mA. And that should be fine for most small relays.

But with all the current being dumped through the LED what can get through to the transistor won't be enough to turn on the relay.

So increasing the resistance of the wire to the LED will decrease the current demands of the LED. And of course you do that by adding a resistor. So let's make that 1kΩ - a decent enough value for a simple indicator LED:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feYeG4.png)</sup>

Now let's do the calculation for the LED's current:

- I = (V<sub>CC</sub> - V<sub>F</sub>) / R = (5 - 2) / 1000 = 3 / 1000 = 3mA

Add that to the 4.3mA that wants to go through the transistor, and we have 7.3mA in total.

Now that is way below what the Arduino's GPIO can provide, so the IO pin is happy, the LED is happy and, most importantly, the transistor is happy.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but its too big to be a comment.  I can't solve your problem, but hopefully I can point you in the right direction.

I think the first problem you have is you have talked this problem in one chunk.  I think even some of the more experienced users would have a problem hitting this in one go.  You need to break it down into simple units (Functional decomposition if you want to be posh).

The problem you are asking about is why your transistor doesn't work.  You have used an LED and you think the correct signals are being sent.

So Phase one, take the transistor and test it in isolation, then you know its working.  Secondly does it still work when the Uno is controlling it rather than just a battery?

Does the object you are powering via the transistor work on its own?
Does it work when you add it to the uno and transistor?

You get the idea.  To be honest I suspect it might be an issue with lack of power.

Comment: thanks @code Gorilla , yes, i guess, i'll have to break it down. somehow, i thought of giving a full picture.

Comment: The either the transistor is broken or its not getting enough current from the uno.

Comment: and:the uno is giving the output signals alright. correctly as per the program. however, the uno output signal is not firing up the transistor. the battery is a secondary circuit. the transistor was supposed to close that secondary circuit .    secondly, yes the object i am trying to power through the transistor works fine.   yes you may be right, the voltage reaching the base of the transistor is 0.7v (due to the 1k ohm resistor, ) i am lowering that value. but somewher i also read that even if the transistor fires, it shall limit the voltage to 4.3 volts . he suggests to use mosfet.